# How to Use Reticulate to import Python function in R shiny App for downloads App

Tags: r, shinyapps, reticulate

I want to use python function in my function.py file and there is one function called run_xi, which is just to extract data from the database and return a data frame to R. However, this code can be run successfully with `data_xi <- data.frame(s = c(1:3),r = c(4:6), x =c(19:21))`but if I replace with the code of using reticulate (showed in the following code), it will fail to generate the csv file, only return me back with a HTML file. Is there any solutions?

```
library(shiny)
library(reticulate)
library(writexl)

#reticulate::source_python("function.py")
#data_xi <- run_xi(26)

if (interactive()) {

  ui <-fluidPage(
    downloadButton("downloadData", "Download Metrics Reports")
  )

  #data_xi <- data.frame(s = c(1:3),r = c(4:6), x =c(19:21)) # uncomment here, code will working
  reticulate::source_python("function.py") # not working when try to use python function by reticulate
  data_xi <- run_xi(26)# not working when try to use python function by reticulate
  server <- function(input,output){



    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

      filename = function(){
        paste(Sys.time(), 'site_mtx.xlsx')
      },

      content = function(file){
        write_xlsx(data_xi, file)
      }
    )
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue that I create another R function using the reticulate function to import the python function and then in the server use the `source` to directly import the r function and then it can be downloaded as an Excel not a html